# Visual Studio Warning when using Stackexchange.Redis Async methods inside a Transaction

Tags: c#, asynchronous, redis, async-await, stackexchange-api

I have the follwowing code:

```cs
var trans = conn.CreateTransaction();
trans.StringSetAsync(keyValuePairs, flags: flags);
trans.SortedSetAddAsync(KeyForAllMessages(), messages.Select(m => new KeyValuePair<RedisValue, double>(m.id, m.id)).ToArray());
trans.SortedSetAddAsync(threadKey, messages.Select(m => new KeyValuePair<RedisValue, double>(m.id, m.id)).ToArray()).GetAwaiter();
return await trans.ExecuteAsync(flags);
```

The above code is inside an async method named:

> public async Task CacheMessagesAsync(....)

VS 2013 underlines the three trans.XXX commands and display a Warning that states:

> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

Although the last command

> return await trans.ExecuteAsync(flags);

means that the method wait for the above commands. 
Why i get the warning? Does this have anything to do with the implementation of the calls of Stackexchange.Redis Api or i'm missing something about writing proper CTP code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're awaiting just one of the async methods.  You should probably be awaiting *all* of the methods, in some way, so that the other three finish by the time the task representing this method finishes.

If it's important that each task finishes before the next starts, then just `await` them all.

If you just need to run all of them but they can all be run in parallel, then you can just pass all of them to `Task.WhenAll` and await *that*.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.
Although note that since i created a transaction any methods that include trans.[some method] will be scheduled by the api asynchcronously until i execute the transaction in the last line.
I think that it may be redis api specific but i thought that since i'm waiting for the transaction.execute is like waiting for all the included async methods.
Are you sure that i should wait for all of them in the specific code?

Comment: @PanKak If you never need to wait for them then there'd be no reason for them to return a `Task` in the first place.

Comment: Indeed but the method trans.ExecuteAsync(...) return a Task<bool>.
So according to your info i removed async from my method declaration and i simply return the task result of trans.ExecuteAsync(...)
That way the caller is responsible for the decision of waiting or not.
Thanks!!!